# how to print all data from a csv file on an image

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i want to print text in each colon from my csv file into a different image but after looping through the colons it's only printing the last  text on the image. i need help please

````
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os
import random

# change directory
os.chdir("C:/Users/V24/Desktop/py_images")

# declare fontsFolder & choose image to print on
my_image = 'python.png'
fontsFolder = 'C:/Windows/Fonts'
fontsFolder = 'fontsfolder'

# reading csv file
a = pd.read_csv("try.csv")

# choose keys
album = a.AlbumID
topics = a.Topics

Name = random.randrange(1,100)
full_name = str(Name) + ".jpg" 

for i,j in zip(album,topics):
     print ('i have album id of : ' + str(i) + ' ' + str(j))
     name = 0
     name = name + 1
     full_name = str(name) + ".jpg" 

     img = Image.open(my_image)
     draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

     fontsFolder = 'fontsfolder'
     arialFont = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(fontsFolder, 'arial.ttf'), 16)
     draw.text((80,70), str(i), font=arialFont, fill=('black'))
     draw.text((80,150), str(j),font=arialFont, fill='midnightblue')
     img.save(full_name)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were looping over an undefined variable

````
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os
import random

# change directory
os.chdir("C:/Users/V24/Desktop/py_images")

# declare fontsFolder & choose image to print on
my_image = 'python.png'
fontsFolder = 'C:/Windows/Fonts'
fontsFolder = 'fontsfolder'

# reading csv file
a = pd.read_csv("try.csv")

# choose keys
album = a.AlbumID
topics = a.Topics

Name = random.randrange(1,100)
full_name = str(Name) + ".jpg" 

name = 0
for i,j in zip(album,topics):  # this is the line that was wrong
     print ('i have album id of : ' + str(i) + ' ' + str(j))
     name = name + 1
     full_name = str(name) + ".jpg" 

     img = Image.open(my_image)
     draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

     fontsFolder = 'fontsfolder'
     arialFont = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(fontsFolder, 'arial.ttf'), 16)
     draw.text((80,70), str(i), font=arialFont, fill=('black'))
     draw.text((80,150), str(j),font=arialFont, fill='midnightblue')
     img.save(full_name)```
````

I do not have the csv file to test, but it should work. Also, as a general remark, it is very dangerous to have variables with just differences in case (Name vs. name). Considering that the 'name' contains a number, it could be called index instead.

Comment: than you pablo ,it was a mistake when i was posting my question initially i used  album and it's not working till now it's printing on the image but it's only printing the last data in the csv file on the picture but i need it to print each data in different picture